# Things you can't change with custom.bib

Tags: natbib, custom-bib

I am using `custom.bib` to create my own citation stile, and I quite like the result!

The only thing I couldn't find, was how I can change some things in the citations in the text. What I miss, is the possibility to reduce the cited name only to the surname

> (Mueller, 2012)

or change the bracket style to these brackets `[]`.

Now it is only like this

> (Johannes Mueller, 2012)

which I think is too long.

If you can give me the solution right away I'd be glad, but I also want to know how to change some things of the `custom.bib` file afterwards by myself and without having to ask every single time.

Edit:

A test file, the edited .bst file and the used .bib file here:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B07uks0ZD0GGUTROd1o4MW1WNG8&usp=sharing

Additionally to say. I'm using LyX and I've activated the natbib package in there and set as option author-year. But I must say it now, that I concentrated a bit more on it, it behaves very strange... LyX doesn't accept any options like `square` for square brackets. They do appear if i use the standard (numerical) option on LyX. If I switch too much between the processor (bibtex8/bibtex/biber/standart) it refuses to do anything and just shows

> ???

What the heck? I mean, is this behavior normal with LyX? I don't feel confident enough to switch to LaTeX because I just can't handle so much code :/

Comment: For BibTeX and modifications look at [tame the beast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). For specific modifications to your style we would need to see it. For more possibilities and easier modifications you might like [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: Normally, `natbib` should *not* include the author's first name in an authoryear-style citation. There may be something amiss either with the way you enter the information in the `author` field or some other aspect of the document related to creating citations. Please edit your posting to (i) show a representative bib entry and (ii) provide a complete MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to solve

Comment: Done! Tame the beast seems to be whole lot of work to get through (man I wish I was a English mother tongue guy), I hope I have the time. Maybe I did a little fault there... I was using tex makebst, is it right that this is part of custombib?

Comment: I would suggest limiting this post to one question, and start another for further problems. Perhaps revert this to just being about reference styles, and start a new one about problems using Lyx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the parentheses to brackets, you can use the [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package. You can specify `square` as an option to the package, or for control of other features too, use the `bibpunct` command, there is an example on this [reference sheet](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php).

I believe that only using the surname is the default way of referencing. Having looked at your `.bib`, I think the issue may be that you have author names stored as `firstname secondname` rather than `secondname, firstname`.

In your `.bib`, the entry is

```
@BOOK{Palgrave2002,
  title = {{T}rees of {S}outhern {A}frica},
  publisher = {4 {R}andom {H}ouse {S}truik ({P}ty) {L}td},
  year = {2002},
  editor = {{L}eni {M}artin},
  author = {{K}eith {C}oates {P}algrave},
  pages = {1212},
  address = {Cape Town - South Africa},
  edition = {Third},
  owner = {Lukas Koch},
  timestamp = {2013.02.25}
}
```

Here you can see the `author` field which needs to be changed to `{{P}algrave, {K}eith {C}oates}`. (I expect that `{Palgrave, Keith Coates}` would work fine too). I would expect that most reference managers should be able to handle this and it shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: Has it something to do with the fact that I'm using LyX maybe? *taking cover*

Comment: Hm, I'm using JabRef to sort my sources and the only thing I have found there, that could  fit to your remarks: Jabref preferences->Entry table->Format of author[...]-> I have ticked "natbib style", 'Show "Lastname, Firstname"' ticked and then "Show last names only" made no difference...

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how you got this information from the .bib file. Where is this standing and how can I change it? (Preferably with JabRef)

Comment: When I change it manually, it works for me, at least the problem, that only surnames should appear... I have yet to figure out how JabRef uses this format as default. Thanks!