# Create own bib style with makebst, but brackets in citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing, custom-bib

I just create with `makebst.tex` my own bibliography style and it works in general. But I have two problems with it:

1. The citation is in square brackets, I did not find the questions concerning this this by creating my style. I tried with `\citep*`, however, latex does not take it. Does anyone know how to remove the brackets?
   [image]
2. The citation with brackets shows up before each line of the references. I really don't know why Latex does it, because I did not set it with makebst.tex. Are there question in `makebst.tex` which lead to this result?
   [image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you loaded the `natbib` package?  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132545/15925.  If that doesn't help please provide details of your set-up including the code used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early on while running the `makebst` utility, you probably came across the following two queries:

[image]

Judging by the screenshot you posted, you selected authoryear-style citation call-outs -- answer `(a)` -- in the upper question, and then selected the default -- answer `(*)` or `natbib` -- in the lower question, regarding the citation management package you'll be working with.

The upshot is that you *must* load the `natbib` package if you wish to use the bespoke bibliography style file which you created with the `makebst` utility.